# Prove that there exists a basis ${v_1},...,{v_m}$ of $V$ such that all the entries in the ﬁrst row of $M(T)$ are $0$ except for...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose ${w_1},...,{w_n}$ is a basis of $W$ and $V$ is ﬁnite-dimensional. Suppose
$T \in L(V,W)$. Prove that there exists a basis ${v_1},...,{v_m}$ of $V$ such
that all the entries in the ﬁrst row of $M(T)$ (with respect to the bases
${v_1},...,{v_m}$ and  ${w_1},...,{w_n}$) are $0$ except for possibly a $1$ in the ﬁrst row,ﬁrst column.

my attempt:
if $rangeT \subseteq span({w_2},...,{w_n})$
we can say $T({v_i}) = 0 \times {w_1} + {a_2} \times {w_2} + ... + {a_n} \times {w_n}$ which ${a_i}$ $i=2,...,n$ can be anything but ${a_1}$ is $0$ and all rows will be $0$.

but I don't know how to prove if $rangeT \not\subset span({w_2},...,{w_n})$

Comment: You should show an attempt(even if incomplete) of resolution

Comment: @Eureka thanks I added it now